# How to handle sub-content in tabGroups in Titanium Mobile

Tags: iphone, mobile, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

What is the designated way to handle alternating content in the active tab of a tabGroup?
In my case I have a tableview with a toolbar on top, and when a row is clicked, I'd like to switch the content in that tab to a new content with a different (edit) toolbar.

In the KitchenSink demo app the window is just replaced as far as I can see. Is this the way to go? How are transitions handled?

Thank you for your answers,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the new window on the current tab:

```
tab.open(newWindow);
```

This will use the standard iOS navigation transition animation.

Also, you can configure a window's navigation bar (top bar) without needing to create and add a toolbar using Window properties like title, leftNavButton, rightNavButton. For example, create an edit button and then do:

```
newWindow.rightNavButton = editButton;
```

Also, you can create a standard edit button by setting the systemButton property to `Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.EDIT`.

Finally, to create a system button with any title, set title property and also set the style property to `Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED`.

Comment: gerry, is it possible to open a new window in the active tab with a transition animation other than the default? I'd like to use a FLIP_FROM_LEFT animation but I can't find out how to do this. Thank you!